# How to share .proto messages across multiple microservices?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, tonic, prost

I'm trying to create a bunch of microservices. Most grpc messages use this message

```
message i18n {
  map<string, string> translations = 0;
}
```

i18n also implements additional methods to choose the right key for the request context. [In this way](https://github.com/danburkert/snazzy/blob/master/src/lib.rs)

I would like to create a Crate that will be stored in the private GitHub repository with proto and additional functionality so I can share i18n message and logic across multiple microservices using cargo.

```
// cargo.toml
[dependencies]
i18n = { git = "url" branch= "main" }
```

Is there any chance I can do it using [*extern_path*](https://github.com/danburkert/snazzy/blob/master/src/lib.rs)?

If not can you share your experience with prost library and how you were sharing code?